# How to highlight menu button on scroll - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, highlight

this is a very common problem but I can't figure it out.
I have a web site in which all sections are all on the same page and you may view them by scrolling. I would like that when I'm in the section "About", the About-button on the menu be highlighted. 
I know how to do it onclick but not on scrolling.

This is my code:

**index.html**:

```
<nav id="nav-wrap">
   <ul id="nav" class="nav">
      <li class="current"><a class="smoothscroll" ng-click="gotoElement('hero')" href="">Home</a></li>
       <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems"><a ng-click="gotoElement(item.id)" href="">{{item.page}}</a>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

**main.js**

```
    angular.module('allApps').service('anchorSmoothScroll', function(){

        this.scrollTo = function(eID) {
            var stopY = elmYPosition(eID)-headerHeigh;
            var sections = $("section"),
            navigation_links = $("#nav-wrap a");

            $('html, body').animate({
                      scrollTop: stopY
            }, 500);


//Highlights menu buttons
        var sections = $("section"),
        navigation_links = $("#nav-wrap a");

        if($("body").hasClass('homepage')) {

            sections.waypoint( {

              handler: function(event, direction) {

                   var active_section;

                    active_section = $(this);
                    if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();

                    var active_link = $('#nav-wrap a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');

                 navigation_links.parent().removeClass("current");
                    active_link.parent().addClass("current");

                },
                offset: '25%'
            });
        }



            function elmYPosition(eID) {
                var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
                var y = elm.offsetTop;
                var node = elm;
                while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
                    node = node.offsetParent;
                    y += node.offsetTop;
                } return y;
            }
        };
    });

        angular.module('allApps').controller('menuCtrl', function($scope, $location, $window, anchorSmoothScroll) {
            $scope.menuItems=[
                              {page:"What WE do", id:"services"},
                              {page:"Why choose US", id:"about"},
                              {page:"our works", id:"portfolio"},
                              {page:"Partner", id:"partner"},
                              {page:"News", id:"news"},
                              {page:"Contact", id:"contact"}
                              ];

            $scope.gotoElement = function (eID){
                $location.hash(eID);
                anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo(eID);
            };
        });
```

**EDIT**
This is the solution suggested by @FrontMonkey

First of all, into the index.html must add this:

```
<script src="js/angular-scroll.js"></script>
```

which could be find [here](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll/blob/master/angular-scroll.js).

The **main.js** is this

```
angular.module('allApps').controller('menuCtrl', function($scope, $location, $document) {
    $scope.menuItems=[
                      {page:"What WE do", id:"services"},
                      {page:"Why choose US", id:"about"},
                      {page:"our works", id:"portfolio"},
                      {page:"Partner", id:"partner"},
                      {page:"News", id:"news"},
                      {page:"Contact", id:"contact"}
                      ];

    /*Scroll function: change background-color of the header*/
    $scope.toTheTop = function() {
        $document.scrollTopAnimated(0, 800);
        var h = $('header').height();
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        var header = $('#main-header');
        if ((y > h + 30 ) && ($(window).outerWidth() > 768 ) ) {
          header.addClass('opaque');
        }else {
             if (y < h + 30) {
                header.removeClass('opaque');
             }else {
                header.addClass('opaque');
             }
        }
    }
}).value('duScrollOffset', 30);
```

Comment: Here is someone's jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vu6hN/28/ 
:D

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply some css

```
 #nav li:hover,#nav li:active{
  background: somecolor;
 }
```